# How to bind Viewdata value into kendo dropdownlist for MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I assign user id and user name in viewdata,How to bind viewdata in dropdownlist using jquery.

```
 <script>

var User=JSON.Parse('@html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["UserDetails"]))');

$("#ddFunctionClub").kendoDropDownList({

          height : 150,

             dataTextField : "Username",

              dataValueField: "UserId",

             ​BindTO: User

           });

<script/>
```

Comment: Any errors? Can you show how you fill `ViewData["UserDetails"]` and with what object?

Comment: No errors,I think my problem is( Bindto:User),

Comment: There is no `BindTO` option. You need `dataSource: User,`

Comment: @Stephan,I already use dataSourse:User,But not work,Can u help me,How to bind method json

Comment: @teovankot ,@stephan ,any method to bind dropdownlist ,Without Using Viewdata .

Comment: Is `var User` returning valid data - i.e. and array of objects containing properties `Username` and `UserId`?

Comment: I return Username and Userid is list format

Comment: I retrive username and Userid from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to serialize your model to json use the following instead:

```
var user = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["UserDetails"]));
```

Your original statement below has a few things wrong with it, incorrect casing for classes, a string around the json and JSON.Parse errors:

```
var User=JSON.Parse('@html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["UserDetails"]))');
```

Your dropdown would then use `dataSource` to bind i.e.

```
$("#ddFunctionClub").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource    : user,
    dataTextField : "Username",
    dataValueField: "UserId"
});
```